# How do I handle this document ready situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully a very simple question. I have some various js functions written as such:

```
var app={
    start:function(){
        //do some stuff and call calculate
    }, //end start
    calculate:function(){
        //do some more stuff
    } //end calculate
}; //end var app

var neato={
    go:function(){
        //do some stuff and call creation
    }, //end go
    creation:function(){
        //do some more stuff
    } //end creation
}; //end var neato
```

Which I could then start as follows:

```
$(document).ready(app.start);
$(document).ready(neato.go);
```

Is there any way I can combine starting both functions in one document ready request?? I just can't seem to figure it out despite trying a few different possibilities.

Comment: With jQuery, you actually don't _need_ to. Multiple document ready handlers are perfectly fine.

Comment: Not related to the question, but the comments like `// end var app` is not good comments, your **editor** will found where it closed.

Comment: Yeah but what if I have just a ton of code and I want to keep all the various functions straight in my head?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an anonymous function and manually call both:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    app.start();
    neato.go();
});
```

If you need to have the value of `this` be `document` in those functions, then use `.call(this)` instead of `()`. And if you need to pass the arguments from the handler, use `.call(this, arguments)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have already will work just fine... but to make it shorter:

```
$(function(){
    app.start();
    neato.go();
});
```

or

```
function startingFunctions(){
    app.start();
    neato.go();
}

$(startingFunction);
```

(note: `$(function(){..});` is the same as document.ready)

Comment: In your second example, it doesn't make sense to use an anonymous function just to call `startingFunction`. It might as well be `$(startingFunction);`